# Rebuilding Links with Django

Tags: html, django, url, url-parameters

I have created a Django app with the URL structure:

```
eventdetails/?event_id=94099
```

This would take me to the index page of the event details app. However My app has sections, and each section needs the event_id to use.

Therefore I need a url structure like:

```
eventdetails/who/?event_id=94099
```

So I can still access the event ID.

Could anyone advise me how to create the links for the navigation or a better way of doing this.

Thanks,

Comment: It's a perfectly ok question. I don't know why it got downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django's URL maps do not take into account the query string, which is passed as is to any view that is mapped.

In practical terms, this means that if you have:

```
url(r'^eventdetails/who/$', 'event_who', name='e-who'),
url(r'^eventdetails/$', 'event_detail', name='e-detail')
```

Then both your view methods will have access to the query string:

```
def event_detail(request):
    id = request.GET.get('event_id')

def event_who(request):
    id = request.GET.get('event_id')
    if not id:
        print 'No ID!'
    else:
        print 'do stuff'
    return render(request, 'who.html')
```

You can also add the event id as part of the url itself, for example `eventdetails/94099/`:

```
url(r'^eventdetails/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'event_detail', name='e-detail')
```

Then your views will be:

```
def event_detail(request, id=None):
    if not id:
        print 'No ID!'
    else:
        print 'do stuff'
    return render(request, 'detail.html')
```

The other benefit you get is that you can easily generate URLs for your events in your templates and views:

```
<ul>
{% for event in events %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'e-detail' id=event.pk %}"> {{ event.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In your view:

```
def go_to_event(request, id):
    return redirect('e-detail', id=id)
```